Difference between 'proper adjective' and 'attributive noun'
In 'the singles party' the noun 'singles' acts as attributive noun modifying 'party'.
There is an English proper adjective 'German', as in 'German people', deriving from the toponym 'Germany'.
Finally, we have the proper noun 'German' in the sense of   'German language in general'.
Here's my question:
In 'the German alphabet', is 'German' to be interpreted as i) the proper adjective 'German' ii) the proper noun 'German' (the language, not, e.g. German citizen), acting as attributive noun modifying 'alphabet' or iii) one or the other; both interpretations are grammatical, maybe different semantics ?

"German alphabet" seems just like "German language."

'language' used in a broad sense here, encompassing written and spoken entities.

OP has asked:

In 'the German alphabet', is 'German' to be interpreted as.
i) the proper adjective 'German'
ii) the proper noun 'German' (the language, not, e.g. German citizen), acting as attributive noun modifying 'alphabet' or
iii) one or the other; both interpretations are grammatical, maybe different semantics ?

In "the German alphabet," "German" specifically refers to the language, rather than the country.
Let's look at the meaning of "proper adjective" and "Attributive nouns"

Proper Adjectives: A proper adjective is an adjective derived from a proper noun. Most language names are proper adjectives. Examples: German, French, Italian, Arabic, Chinese.
Attributive Nouns::An attributive noun is a noun that modifies another noun. Considering language and their alphabets, examples include:


The German alphabet
The French alphabet
The Italian alphabet
The Arabic alphabet
The Chinese alphabet

"In these cases, the language name ("German", "French", etc.) can be interpreted as both a 'proper adjective" and an "attributive noun".

'Most language names are proper adjectives[…]'. Really?

@Peterש Could you please explain your comment? There is an English proper adjective 'German', as in 'German people', deriving from the toponym 'Germany'. German itself is also a noun.

I think the noun German came before the noun Germany.

https://www.britannica.com/topic/German-language
